# Check if the client did not receive the message

Tags: socket.io

I'm building a chat.

With `send()`, I can know if the client received the message, but I don't know how to **check if the client didn't receive it**. Which is what I need to be able to define when to issue a notification.

- server side:

```
socket.on(
        'send_message',
        async (room, message) => {

            //some code.

            socket.to(room).emit('received_message', message);

            return socket.on('message', function (message) {
                // here I know, the client received the message.
              });

            // if ( did_not_receive ) handlePushNotification();
        }
);
```

- client side:

```
socket.on('received_essage', (response) => {
            setResponse(response);

            socket.send('hi');
        });
```

Comment: The only way to know if the client received a message is if it responds to the message.  So, you need to run some kind of timer and stop it if a response arrives. If the timer elapses, resend the message or close the connection.

Comment: Precisely what I was trying to do but I don't know how?! Since "on('message')" is only called in the case of a received message.

Comment: You start the timer *before/when* you send the message, then stop the timer if the message is responded to. If the timer elapses, it means the response never arrived. Of course, that could mean the original message was lost, or that it was received but the response was lost. The sender has no way to differentiate.